# How to open a random picture in a catalog?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have an unknown list of folders and subfolders containing pictures
I want to run 10 random pictures at 30 second intervals
If possible, close the previous one after the timer expires.

I tried to assemble it myself but I don't have enough knowledge to do it

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
TIMEOUT [/T] timeout [/NOBREAK]
set list=d
set e=0
set papka = cd /d "%~dp0

for /d /r %papka% %%i in (*.*) do (
  @if exist "%%i" (
    @set _variable=%%i
    @echo !_variable!
    for %%f   in (%_variable% *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png) do (
      @echo Filename: '%%f'
      set list=%list%;%%f 
      set /a e+=1
      @echo count: %e%
    )

    )
  )



for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
 @echo %%a
)


set n=0
for %%f in (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png) do set /a n+=1
echo Total files %n%

set /a i = %RANDOM% %% n
echo Going to open %i%

set q=0
for %%f in (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png) do (
  if %i%==!q! set file=%%f
  set /a q+=1
)
echo Filename: %file%
start "" "%file%"
pause
```

in `for %%f   in (%_variable% *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png)`
I tried to force search for pictures on the way from _variable
But I only get files from the first folder and I need from the folder along the path to _variable
Afterwards I want to put all the paths to the pictures into an array
And get a random index

From

```
set list="D:\temp\Desktop\605e4478cc373aa28530b2a05273b4e3.jpg"
set e=0
set papka = cd /d "%~dp0
start "" "D:\temp\Desktop\605e4478cc373aa28530b2a05273b4e3.jpg"

for /d /r %papka% %%i in (*.*) do (
  @if exist "%%i" (
    @set _variable=%%i
    @echo Folder !_variable!
    for %%f   in (%_variable% *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png) do (
      @echo PathFile: '!_variable!\%%f'
      set list=%list%;!_variable!\%%f
      set /a e+=1
      @echo count: %e%
    )

    )
  )

pause
for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
start "" "%a%"
)
pause
```

I get

```
Folder D:\temp\Desktop\Folder\Folder (5)\Folder
PathFile: 'D:\temp\Desktop\Folder\Folder (5)\Folder\01beeb78e0cdce4e6846629a6b8d0626.jpg'
count: 0
PathFile: 'D:\temp\Desktop\Folder\Folder (5)\Folder\605e4478cc373aa28530b2a05273b4e3.jpg'
count: 0
Folder D:\temp\Desktop\Folder\Folder (5)\Folder (2)
PathFile: 'D:\temp\Desktop\Folder\Folder (5)\Folder (2)\01beeb78e0cdce4e6846629a6b8d0626.jpg'
count: 0
PathFile: 'D:\temp\Desktop\Folder\Folder (5)\Folder (2)\605e4478cc373aa28530b2a05273b4e3.jpg'
count: 0
Folder D:\temp\Desktop\Folder\Folder (5)\Folder (2)\3
PathFile: 'D:\temp\Desktop\Folder\Folder (5)\Folder (2)\3\01beeb78e0cdce4e6846629a6b8d0626.jpg'
count: 0
PathFile: 'D:\temp\Desktop\Folder\Folder (5)\Folder (2)\3\605e4478cc373aa28530b2a05273b4e3.jpg'
count: 0
```

Comment: Can you describe what problems you're still having with the script?

Comment: @u1686_grawity I have added more information

Answer (score 1):

I would *strongly* recommend writing scripts in PowerShell instead of Cmd. It's much more consistent – and the task can be achieved in one line:

```
Start-Process (Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Get-Random)
```

(or, using default aliases, `start (dir -file -recurse | get-random)`.)

> I need from the folder along the path to _variable

Then just concatenate them together:

```
set list=%list%;!_variable!\%%f
```

or:

```
set list=%list%;%%i\%%f
```

because the 'parent' iterator variables remain accessible here.

> I tried to force search for pictures on the way from _variable

You don't need `for /f` here – and you probably don't need `for /d` either; you can directly perform a recursive search using `for /r`:

```
for /r %dir% %%f in (*.jpg *.jpeg *.png) do ...
```

Note that the list is **space**-separated, not comma-separated.

> Afterwards I want to put all the paths to the pictures into an array

Cmd scripts do not have arrays. At best, you can kind-of mimic arrays using either a massive string variable containing space-delimited names (which won't work if your file names themselves have spaces!), or using delayed expansion and a ton of numbered variables ("variable variables"), e.g. `!files.%i%!` to access variables `files.1`, `files.2`, etc. Your current solution of performing the `for...` loop twice is probably going to work better than that, I suspect.

Comment: The problem is that in the code from `for %%f   in (%_variable% *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png) do (` I always get `01beeb78e0cdce4e6846629a6b8d0626.jpg` `605e4478cc373aa28530b2a05273b4e3.jpg` but there are other files in the folders and after `list=%list%;!_variable!\%%f` I can not open in `for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
 start "" "%a%"
 )`

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off && cd /d "D:\The\Full\Path\To\Your\Pictures\Images\Folder"

%:^)
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f delims^= %%G in =;(' dir /o:-d /on /b *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.png ^| findstr /xig:.\list.txt ^| find /v /c ""
    ');= do set /a "_total=%%~G, _cnt=1" && echo/Total files: 00%%~G

for /f usebackq^delims^= %%G in =;(` dir /o:-d /on /b *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.png ^| findstr /r .* ^| findstr /xig:.\list.txt
    `);= do call set /a "_i+=1+0" && call set "_f_%%_i%%=%%~G" && call set "_nx_i=%%~nxG"

for /l %%L in =;( 001, 001, !_total! );= do if !_cnt! equ 1 =;(
      set /a "_rand_1=!random!*!_total!/32768+1, _x=!random!*!_total!/32768+1, _cnt+=1"
    );= >nul else if !_cnt! leq 30 =;( 
      set _rand_ | findstr /e "_rand_..=!_x!" || call set /a "_rand_!_cnt!=!_x!, _x=!random!*!_total!/32768+1, _cnt+=1"
    );= >nul else goto %:^[

timeout /t 30 /nobreak | >nul =;(
     for /l %%L in =;( 01,01,10 );= do %ComSPec% /v /c "<con: call start "" "!_f_%%_rand_%%~L%%!"" 
    );= & endlocal & goto %:^)
```

---

What you have to do is more complicated than it seems and involves:

**1.** Check the file listing output and check if there are listed in the file

**2.** Get the sum of existing files present in the list excluding those that do not exist

**3.** Save files one by one in an array and make it "retrievable" in indexed form

**4.** Monitor the values ​​of each definition that points to the rondomic value at run time

**5.** Check if any rondomic value was generated in duplicate and in a "unique" case, after, create variable associated with predefined array variable with pair in array (also in a non-repetitive way)

**6.** Remove/Reset the variable/values ​​after 30 seconds of timeout for new looping

---